# C++ Class Inheritance problem

Tags: c++, inheritance, class, copy-constructor, virtual-copy

Hi I have two classes, one called Instruction, one called LDI which inherits from instruction class.

```
class Instruction{

  protected:
    string name;
    int value;

  public:
    Instruction(string _name, int _value){ //constructor
        name = _name;
        value = _value;
    }
    ~Instruction(){}
    Instruction (const Instruction &rhs){
        name = rhs.name;
        value = rhs.value;
    }
    void setName(string _name){
        name = _name;
    }
    void setValue(int _value){
        value = _value;
    }
    string getName(){
        return name;
    }
    int getValue(){
        return value;
    }
    virtual void execute(){}
    virtual Instruction* Clone() { 
        return new Instruction(*this); 
    }
};
/////////////end of instruction super class //////////////////////////

class LDI : public Instruction{

    void execute(){
        //not implemented yet
    }
    virtual Instruction* Clone(){
        return new LDI(*this);
    }
};
```

Then I create a pointer of type Instruction and try to make point to a new instance of type LDI.

```
Instruction* ptr;
ptr = new LDI("test", 22);
```

I get the following compiler errors. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
functions.h:71: error: no matching function for call to ‘LDI::LDI(std::string&, int&)’
classes.h:54: note: candidates are: LDI::LDI()
classes.h:54: note:                 LDI::LDI(const LDI&)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code: `new LDI(name, val)` specifically says "Call the LDI constructor with a `name` and `val`."

There is no LDI constructor that takes `name / val`.
In fact, I don't see a constructor for LDI at all.

If you want to use the constructor of a base-class, here is how:

```
public LDI(string _name, int _value) // Public constructor for LDI
    : Instruction(_name, _value)     // Delegate to the base-class constructor
{
    // Do more LDI-specific construction here
}
```

Comment: Note that C++0x will allow importing the constructors of the base class with a `using` directive, and that is great.

Answer (score 3):

```
LDI::LDI (string _name, int _value):Instruction(_name,_value){}
```

You need to provide a constructor for derived class `LDI`, which in turn calls the correct Base class constructor.

```
ptr = new LDI("test", 22);
```

At this moment compiler looks for a `LDI` constructor which takes `(string,int)` as arguments, Since there is no such constructor provided the compiler cribs.

```
LDI(string _name, int _value)
{ 
}
```

By providing the derived class constructor will solve the compilation issue. But by default the derived class constructor will not call appropriate base class constructor; in this case `Instruction(_name,_value)`( it calls only the default constructor).
In order to call correct base class constructor you need to invoke the base class constructor from derived class initializer list.

so.

```
LDI::LDI (string _name, int _value):Instruction(_name,_value){}
```

Answer (score 1):

Constructors, destructors, assignment operator, friend functions and friend classes of base classes are not inherited by derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all you must define and declare constructor for LDI (string _name, int _value). You myst initialize your base class constructor also LDI::LDI (string _name, int _value):Instruction(_name,_value){}.
Second it will be good if add vritual keyword before your base class destructor. If your base class destructor not virtual and you write this code 
Instruction* ptr;
ptr = new LDI("test", 22);
delete *ptr;

destructor for LDI never called. Keep base class destructor virtual for correct destroy for your hierarchy of objects